# Petición AJAX con Advanced Rest Client funciona pero desde Jquery no

Tags: jquery, ajax, soap

Tengo que hacer una petición a un webservice SOAP, enviando el request con Advanced Rest Client con la siguiente configuración funciona:
[image: Configuracion funcional]

Pero con el siguiente código usando Jquery, no:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
        url: "https://....asmx",
        contentType: "application/soap+xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    data: soapBody,
    processData: false,
    success: function( response ){
        console.log(response)
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log( "ERROR", arguments );
    }
});
```

Sale el siguiente error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://....asmx. Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Estuve leyendo que tiene que ver con CORS, pero ¿hay algo que pueda hacer del lado del cliente? ¿Por que funciona con ARC pero no desde localhost con XAMPP?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿ Que te sale en la consola ? Cuando entra en `error: XXX` ?

Comment: Perdón! Me olvidé de incluirlo, ahí lo agregué! Gracias!

Comment: Échale un ojo a https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné instalando el plugin `CORS` de Google Chrome, de esa forma setea todos los flags desde el cliente necesarios para realizar la petición.